# What is the fundamental group of this pattern of circles?

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

I am trying to compute $\pi_1(X)$ where $X$ is the following collection of circles:

$$ X = \left[\bigcup_{(m,n) \in \mathbb{Z}^2} (m+ in) + S^1 \right] \cup \left[\bigcup_{(m,n) \in \mathbb{Z}} \big((m + \tfrac{1}{2}) + i (n + \tfrac{1}{2}) \big) + (1 - \sqrt{2})S^1 \right]$$

I have computed the formula to make the circle tangent patterns to be what it looks like. This is possibly related to the [truncated square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_square_tiling) tiling.

There is an action $\mathbb{Z}^2 \times  X \to X$ leaving this space invariant, so this is a [covering space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/34238/why-is-a-covering-space-of-a-torus-t-homeomorphic-either-to-mathbbr2-s) $X \to Y$.  So perhaps it's sufficient to compute $\pi_1(X/\mathbb{Z}^2)$.

[image]

Comment: this is a 1-dimensional CW complex with a countably infinite number of cells. So the fundamental group is free of countable rank.

Answer (score 5):

This space is just a graph (consider the intersection points of the circles as vertices and the arcs connecting them as edges).  Modding out a spanning tree, it is thus homotopy equivalent to a wedge of circles.  It is clear there must be countably infinitely many circles, so $\pi_1(X)$ is a free group on countably infinitely many generators.